# Disappearing files, refactoring mess

Tags: ios, xcode, file, refactoring

I'm pretty green, but I'm trying to modify a simple program to fit my own needs. You may remember the "BirdWatching" app from "Your Second iOS App: Storyboards" in the iOS Developer's Library.

Anyway, I've refactored most of the names, etc., successfully (it still worked), but then I tried to get rid of a file that kept appearing, even though its name had been expunged (or so I thought) through refactoring. Shows up in the Assistant Editor, right next to the file to which it was refactored.

Now I've got a mess. I tried to move the entire project into it's own folder, but now the compliler won't recognize the info-plist file (says it doesn't exist, and two other files are showing up in red, depending on their position in the navigator. However, it's the WMDG-info.plist that the complier complains about. Specifically, it appears to be following the old path to the file, even after it's been moved and re-added.

I've tried quitting and restarting xCode, re-adding the files, etc. I've searched under every keyword I can think of, but can't find a solution.

Please help!

Thanks!

--Tim

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try rebuilding ? your plist file probably contains data as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654470/plist-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it) if you want to rename it , I see a `.pch` having the same name try to rename both. and then search if that name is used in the code.

Comment: This is also useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538484/does-anybody-know-what-the-xcode-file-infoplist-strings-english-is

Comment: @Mehdi  How do you rebuild? thanks!

Comment: in the upper menu, there is Product -> Build or (clean) or Build For -> ... you play arround with them, but the plist file is required as it has variables in it that will be used by the app.